# Increase the quality of the screen recorder in iOS

Tags: ios

I like the screen recorder in iOS 12, but I was hoping that it would get more frames per second.

I don't see any settings screen. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't missing anything. There are no settings whatsoever that you can change to customize the capture characteristics of the built-in iOS screen recorder.

- [How to record the screen on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207935)

However, a simple [Web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=3rd+party+screen+recording+app+ios) reveals a bunch of 3rd party iOS/macOS/Windows screen recording apps that you can try out to see if they offer better quality/cutomizations.

- https://filmora.wondershare.com/screen-recorder/best-ios-screen-recorder.html
- https://www.aiseesoft.com/screen-recorder/iphone-screen-recorder-app.html
- https://itunes.apple.com/app/techsmith-capture/id1266321056
- https://iphonebyte.com/iphone-screen-recorder-apps/